# Create resource from model when User signs up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, model-view-controller, model

I'm trying to create a resource `Mission` when a new user is signed up. Mission has a foreign key `Location` as well.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :create_mission

  private
  def create_mission
    Mission.create(user: self, location_id: 1, name: 'Mission 1')
  end
end
```

But this code doesn't work unfortunately. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :create_mission

  private
  def create_mission
    missions.create! location_id: 1, name: 'Mission 1'
  end
end
```

Now your error could be visible with `create!`. Try this.

Answer (score 1):

I do not recommend you to create relations in callbacks. It will hurt you if you will need to create user in another action or in console. Better to create it in controller after creation (in some service object in the future)

```
def create
  if @user.save
    @user.missions.create(...)
  end
end
```

And you can use debugger to check errors dynamically (shipped with rails https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug, just insert 'debugger' in your code), probably you have some validation error.